# Sequelize order association one way and main results another way

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models Chat and Message. The association is `Chat.hasMany(Messages)`.

I want to run a query to order these models on the Message model's sentDate field.

```
const chats = await Chat.findAll({
    where: { userId },
    include: {
        model: Message,
        as: 'messages'
    },
    order: [['messages', 'sentDate', 'desc']], 
});
```

The code above will order chats and each chats' messages in the way you'd expect; in descending order.

What I'm curious about is if there's a way to modify this query to keep the chats ordered by `sentDate, desc` but have the messages in the include ordered by `sentDate, asc`?

Comment: I suppose you can do it only if you include messages twice

Comment: Do you mean like this? `order: [['sentDate', 'desc'], ['messages', 'sentDate', 'asc']]`.  You can also delete the 'asc' from the 2nd element in the array as asc is the default.

Comment: @Emma I think the problem I'd have with that ordering is that the sentDate field is only on the Message model. I would get an 'unknown column sentDate' error.

Comment: Do you want to order chats by the latest `sentDate` amongst the related messages by desc and within the messages, it should be asc?  something like this `order: [[Sequelize.literal('MAX(messages.sentDate) OVER (PARTITION BY chats.id)'), 'desc'], ['messages', 'sentDate']]`?  You might need to adjust column names for the partition.

Comment: Correct, that's how I want it ordered. I've never used PARTITION BY or OVER so I'll have to read into the docs on those to see if I can make them work. Thanks for the assistance.